# Prisma, TS and getServerSideProps, I'm stuck

Tags: next.js, prisma

I am trying to make a simple query via Prisma in my Nextjs app, no errors but cant get any results back and console.log is not working in within my: getServerSideProps ...

What am I missing? There is Data in the CasinoComment table (submitted/added via axios)  which I can view via prisma studio, and I do not see any errors...

**comments.tsx**

```
import { GetServerSideProps, GetStaticProps } from "next";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

import { CasinoComment } from "@prisma/client";
import prisma from "../../lib/prisma";

type Props = {
  comments?: CasinoComment;
};

export default function Comment({ comments }: Props) {
 
  console.log(comments);
  ...
}


export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  console.log("test222");

  const comments = await prisma.casinoComment.findMany();
  console.log(comments);
  return {
    props: { comments },
  };
};
```

**schema.prisma**

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  casino_comments CasinoComment[]
}


model CasinoComment {
  id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  casinoId    Int
  content     String   @db.VarChar(2000)
  reply       Boolean?
  parentId    Int?
  approved    Boolean
  likes       Int?
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt
  author      User @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId    String
}
```

**lib/prisma.js**

```
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      prisma: PrismaClient;
    }
  }
}

let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    prisma = new PrismaClient();
  } else {
    if (!global.prisma) {
      global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
    }

    prisma = global.prisma;
  }
}

export default prisma;
```

Comment: What does it mean -- declare let global: { prisma: PrismaClient };

Answer (score 1):

This works great for me.

```
export default function Comment(props: any) {
 
  console.log("Props are",  props); // to see data
  ...
}


export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const comments = await prisma.casinoComment.findMany();
    return {
      props: {
        comments: comments
      },
    };
  }
```

Comment: I found out the problem... Was trying to use getServerSideProps in a component :(  but thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I tried to use getServerSideProps in a component :/ Lesson learnt!

Comment: thank you thank you .. i've been banging my head